# Disable and Enable Text when button is pressed in HTML?

Tags: html

How should i disable my text **Click Begin Game to start** when **Begin Button** is pressed ? It keep displaying after begin button is pressed.

HTML CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="./arrows/clubbackground.jpg" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsRev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>DDR-Project 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="BackgroundScene">
  <div id="DanceScoreboard">
    <div id="GameStopped"><button id="StartBtn" class="btnStyle" onclick="gameStarted=true;">Begin Game</button>
      <br><br><br>
      <div class="Status">Click Begin Game to start</div>
    </div>
    <div id="GameRunning"><button id="StopBtn" class="btnStyle" onclick="history.go(0);">Stop Game</button>
      <div id="Status" class="Status"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<p style="color:blue;">Points Earned:</p>
<div id="dancePoints" class="Points"><div class="OutputText" id="CorrectCount">0</div>
    </div>
  <div class="stage"></div>
  <!-- ENDS .STAGE -->
  <div id="controls">
    <img id="left" src="./arrows/staticLeft.png">
    <img id="up" src="./arrows/staticUp.png">
    <img id="down" src="./arrows/staticDown.png">
    <img id="right" src="./arrows/staticRight.png">
  </div>
  <!-- ENDS #CONTROLS -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what your are looking for . please check...

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="./arrows/clubbackground.jpg" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsRev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>DDR-Project 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="BackgroundScene">
  <div id="DanceScoreboard">
    <div id="GameStopped"><button id="StartBtn" class="btnStyle" onclick="gameStarted=true;">Begin Game</button>
      <br><br><br>
      <div class="Status">Click Begin Game to start</div>
    </div>
    <div id="GameRunning"><button id="StopBtn" class="btnStyle" onclick="history.go(0);">Stop Game</button>
      <div id="Status" class="Status"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<p style="color:blue;">Points Earned:</p>
<div id="dancePoints" class="Points"><div class="OutputText" id="CorrectCount">0</div>
    </div>
  <div class="stage"></div>
  <!-- ENDS .STAGE -->
  <div id="controls">
    <img id="left" src="./arrows/staticLeft.png">
    <img id="up" src="./arrows/staticUp.png">
    <img id="down" src="./arrows/staticDown.png">
    <img id="right" src="./arrows/staticRight.png">
  </div>
  <!-- ENDS #CONTROLS -->
  <script>
  jQuery('#StartBtn').click(function(){
  jQuery('.Status').hide();
  })  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional line to the `onclick` event for the `Begin Game` button.

HTML

```
<div id="GameStopped"><button id="StartBtn" class="btnStyle" onclick="beginGame()">Begin Game</button>
      <br><br><br>
  <div class="Status" id="ClickToBeginMessage">Click Begin Game to start</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function beginGame(){
  gameStarted=true;
  $("#ClickToBeginMessage").hide()
}
```